# Why is my sprite displayed offset from its Box2D body?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, rotation, coordinates

I found out about this using a debug renderer. When the game starts, everything is in order. But when a collision happens, the sprite's rotation is way larger than its body. The sprite and body match when the body is completely horizontal.

[image: sprites with Box2D body outlines as overlay]

The sprite's rotation origin seems far distant from where it should be. Here's my code:

```
Sprite sprite = data.sprite;
position = body.getPosition();
sprite.setPosition(
    position.x - sprite.getWidth()  / 2,
    position.y - sprite.getHeight() / 2
);
sprite.setOrigin(position.x, position.y);
sprite.setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * body.getAngle());
```

As you can see, I am even trying to set center of its rotation with `setOrigin` without success. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most APIs represent the Sprite's origin in local space, not in world space. This is supported by libgdx's documentation which states:

> A Sprite also has an origin around which rotations and scaling are performed (that is, the origin is not modified by rotation and scaling). The **origin is given relative to** the bottom left corner of the Sprite, **its position**.

So I think that if you want rotations to happen around the center of the sprite, you should be using the following origin instead:

```c
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: You are really fast. You are right about setOrigin. That was the trick. Thanks a lot! BTW, setPosition statement should be from mine. You need to set corner point for sprite position.

Comment: @Paul I noticed the problem and edited my post but you had already commented. :) In some APIs the origin also affects translation (which is why I initially wrote a different setPosition) but then I checked the documentation and found out that's not the case with libgdx so your setPosition was correct.