# box2d not centered in sprite

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am trying to create a bounding box for my sprite using box2d, but the box is being created at the wrong spot. I followed a tutorial on the wiki using this code

```
    BodyDef bodyDef1 = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef1.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef1.position.set(player.getX(), player.getY());
    playerBody = world.createBody(bodyDef1);
    PolygonShape square = new PolygonShape();
    square.setAsBox(player.getWidth() / 2, player.getHeight() / 2);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef1 = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef1.shape = square;
    fixtureDef1.density = 0.1f;
```

Player is a just the sprite that I am trying to create the box around.

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to GDSE. Have you seen [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22555/34569)? Does it answer your question as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of a Box2D body is defined as its center. So if you set the body's position to the lower left corner of the Sprite, then it will be displayed as you showed in the image.

What you need to do is set the Body's position to the center of the Sprite like so:

```
bodyDef1.position.set(player.getX() + player.getWidth() / 2, player.getY() + player.getHeight() / 2);
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. My problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @user64317 Do you have the sprite moving around the screen? When adjusting the body you might have forgotten to apply my fix there. Or possibly you are setting the sprite's position based on the body's position, which you lead you to the same problem. You would then have to subtract half of the sprite's height in width.

Comment: Ah I have the sprites position being set based on the bodies position in my update method. Thanks!